# Is cache access token in msal safe?

Tags: azure-ad-msal

Many code examples suggest to use token cache provided by msal to cache the access token and to take advantage of the nice feature that msal can silently acquiring token. But how does msal protect the access token in cache? Is it safe or can it be easily hacked?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The security of the cache depends on which token cache you use, generally dictated by your application's scenario. I'll focus on MSAL.NET from here but similar concepts apply to the libraries in other languages and environments.

In [.NET web apps and APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization?tabs=aspnet), there are several options available including in-memory and distributed caches such as Redis, SQL Server, Cosmos DB, or a custom solution. In-memory caching is only accessible from the same process. For distributed caches, it is the responsibility of the developer to protect these data sources from unauthorized access and instrument them to detect when a security breach has occurred.

In [.NET desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization?tabs=desktop) and [mobile apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization?tabs=mobile), token caching uses [OS-specific tools](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/Cross-platform-Token-Cache#encryption-and-storage) for encrypting and storing tokens. How access is granted to tokens stored in these are [OS-specific](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/Cross-platform-Token-Cache#security-boundary).

In all cases (except mobile), you can [write your own, custom token serialization and caching mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization?tabs=custom). I don't recommend this for all but the most advanced scenarios.